# One aspx page to have utf-8 encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, utf-8

What should I do to change one aspx page to have utf-8 encoding?

my web.config has the following code:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization
     requestEncoding="utf-8"
     responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
</system.web>
```

Tried this:

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this;

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <globalization
    fileEncoding="utf-8" 
    requestEncoding="utf-8" 
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-US"
    uiCulture="de-DE"
   />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To set the encoding for an individual page, set the `RequestEncoding` and `ResponseEncoding` attributes of the `@ Page` directive:

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Or you can use `location` like this:

```
<location path="home.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Read more: [How to: Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx)

Comment: what is culture="en-US"
  uiCulture="de-DE"

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar ... Just an example.

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar ... culture affects culture-dependent functions like money, date formatting and so on, while uiculture affects what resources are loaded for the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

In your `Page_Load` if you want to do it dynamically.