# UTF-8 - Oracle, Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Entity Framework Core and Oracle. When I used Oracle entity for saving in the database, I cannot save with UTF-8 for DB. This is some my package already installed base on .NET Core 2.2:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6">
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.19.60" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="2.19.60" />
```

This is the model class configuration:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasColumnName("NAME")
      .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(255)")
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
      .HasDefaultValue("Tiếng việt có dấu")
      .IsUnicode();
```

Datatype in Oracle database is `NVARCHAR2` too. But it doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost(ApiRoutes.User.AddUser)]
public IActionResult addUser([FromBody] WtUser entity)
{
    try
    {
        // _UserService.Add(entity);
        // _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        dbContext.WtUser.Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChange();

        return Ok("Ok add success");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok("Failed " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is my input:

```
 "Name": "Tuổi trẻ Việt Nam có dấu",
```

Output

```
 "Name": "Tu¿i tr¿ Vi¿t Nam có d¿u",
```

Somebody help me please!

Comment: What does your type `WtUser` look like??

Comment: It is normal class with some filed

 public string Name { get; set; }

Comment: What is your database character set? What do you get when you query database with `select DUMP(NAME, 1016) from ...`?

Comment: This is my character set DB
**NLS_CHARACTERSET               WE8MSWIN1252  **
When I input inside DB is ok, But I use entity framework by entity framework not correct type unicode??

Comment: Where do you output? To the console?

Comment: Perhaps this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283697/one-aspx-page-to-have-utf-8-encoding