# How to display words with accented characters in HTML input inside an ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am trying to pass a French word from `Controller` to `View` using `viewbag` (*The word that I try to pass is :* **Espèce**), but inside the `view` when I try to affect the `viewbag` value's to an **HTML** `input` *type text* all I see is : **`Esp&#233;ce`** .

**In Controller**

```
ViewBag.T = "Espèce";
```

**In View :** I used *Jquery* to affect the value

```
$("#T").val("@ViewBag.T").focus();
```

**The HTML Input**

```
<div>

    <input type="type" id="T" value="" />

</div>
```

**The result**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One aspx page to have utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283697/one-aspx-page-to-have-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an encoding issue. I'd recommend UTF-8 to ensure you get the accent marks to show up correctly.

From the [Microsoft ASP.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/39d1w2xf(v=vs.100)):

> To set the encoding for all pages, add a Globalization property to the
> Web.config file, and then set its fileEncoding, requestEncoding, and
> responseEncoding attributes, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> <configuration>   
>  <system.web>
>    <globalization
>       fileEncoding="utf-8"
>       requestEncoding="utf-8"
>       responseEncoding="utf-8"
>       culture="en-US"
>       uiCulture="de-DE"
>     />   
>  </system.web> 
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: No change bro I tried this but no change, please any other help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below jquery code it will work as you expected. But it may introduce an XSS vulnerability. You can refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419664/12883315).

```
$("#T").val($("<div/>").html("@ViewBag.T").text()).focus();
```

Comment: Looks like there's another answer in the question you linked that addresses this without the security vulnerability: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395954/3712532

Comment: Hope that answer fixed your issue.